# Updating Web Site Address Error - A list, survey, discussion board, or document library with the specified title already exists in this Web site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

We are trying to update the **Web Site Address** of a subsite and would like to do so via **Site Settings** -> **Title, Description, and Logo**.

[image]

However we are getting the following error when accessing the *Title, Description, and Logo** page:

> A list, survey, discussion board, or document library with the specified title already exists in this Web site. Please choose another title.

There are a number of solutions online recommending to delete the **'Site Assets'** library, however this is not feasible for us as this is a Production site.

Appreciate if someone can advice what other solutions we have to update the **Web Site Address**, and also, how do we go about fixing this problem.

Thanks.

[image]